# Where to learn algebraic analysis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, sheaf-theory, several-complex-variables

I have been studying categories, sheaf cohomology and complex analysis (the basics since I know just a little). Then recently I tried to find out more about algebraic analysis and these microlocal stuffs, but I couldn't find any introductory material.

I know about the books and papers by Kashiwara and they are a little advanced for me. (However, I have never seen *Foundations of algebraic analysis* since this book is not so easily found.) Any material, lecture notes, etc are welcome.

Comment: Hello - I have a copy of "Foundations of algebraic analysis". Please let me know (uncookedfalcon@gmail.com) if you are interested.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a link to [Foundations of Algebraic Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691084130) by Masaki Kashiwara, Takahiro Kawai, and Tatsuo Kimura. It's not available from, new, from Amazon, but is available as a used book for purchase.

You might want to search a university library for the text, to see if it meets your needs before considering purchasing it. If not available at your library, you might want to request it through inter-library loan.

I'd suggest Googling [Mikio Sato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikio_Sato), who is credited for having *started* the field of Algebraic Analysis.

There is also an entry on Wikipedia which may give you some directions for further searching: [Algebraic Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_analysis), with links to entries on the territories that overlap with the field.

Here is a webpage with links to [online books and lecture notes](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~delidumanc/math.html) in some of the sub-fields you mention (e.g., [algebraic geometry](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/lecturenotes.html)).

Answer (score 5):

[KKK] "Foundations of Algebraic analysis" is not easy for beginners, I highly recommend to read A. Kaneko's "Introductions to Hyperfunctions", and Morimoto "An introduction to Sato's Hyperfunctions". And there is another one "Fundamentals of Algebraic microlocal analysis" by Struppa and Kato, also very good. [SKK]/LNM 287 is another classical book, but very hard to read. Please try to search M. Sato, M. Kashiwara, P. Schapira, and else.