# Questions about algebraic analysis: prerequesites, references and state of the field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, smooth-manifolds, sheaf-theory, complex-manifolds

I'm interested in studying algebraic analysis, specifically the area described in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_analysis and also the theory of D-modules, as I find the idea of "doing analysis with algebra" quite attractive and also because it seems like a very rich field in terms of the present underlying interactions between various fields in mathematics. I'm a graduate student, having covered the basics of Smooth Manifolds, Commutative Algebra, some Algebraic Geometry, some Functional Analysis, and also quite a bit of Complex Analysis in one variable. I'm wondering about:

- What are the prerequesites to study algebraic analysis and what is recommended to be comfortable with when getting into it?

I'm guessing I'll need to know a lot of Geometry, e.g. Symplectic Geometry, Complex manifolds, Algebraic Geometry and a lot of Category theory and Sheaf theory. I'm not sure if there's more I need to study from functional analysis and PDE's as well.
I would like to know the prerequesites so that I can have a clear path to get to algebraic analysis.

All comments and answers are appreciated and I thank you in advance :)

Comment: Ok, I can specify. What I meant by algebraic analysis is the area described in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_analysis and D-modules for example

Comment: The wikipedia description looks indeed a bit narrower: "it deals with systems of linear partial differential equations by using sheaf theory and complex analysis". I suppose you already know about some of these things.

Comment: I’d refer to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268375/where-to-learn-algebraic-analysis

Comment: Thank you, but I had seen that post, but it doesn't answer two of my questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to learn algebraic analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268375/where-to-learn-algebraic-analysis)

Comment: Sorry but that’s the same post as the above one